# include prototype helper in cakeph2x

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp-2.0

hi i am new in cakephp 2x.
i am working on the backend and i did some insert update and delete in it.
i also did the pagination in the cakephp with ajax. now i want to create the popup for the seatch functionality. i want to use the modalbox.js for that prototype.js and scriptaculas.js
but when i need this all the ajax is stopped working. i dont know why.
i read the just insert as helper so i write this code in the controller

```
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','Session','Ajax','Js'=> array('Prototype','Scriptaculous'));
```

now tell me what to do the next ?
i have included the helper but from where i can found this helper file ?
i just want to open the popup file

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The ajax stop working, may be because of the compatibility factor of those js files. But you can't enter js files as helper files. Only helper files can be on helper folder under view folder.